# Nesting aggregate functions in Librato

Tags: librato

I have 3 measures, and I want to add `measure1` and `measure2` and then subtract `measure3` from the result. I'm unable to get the composite metric below to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
subtract([
    sum([
        sum(s("measure1", "*")),
        sum(s("measure2", "*")),
    ]),
    sum(s("measure3", "*"))
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the issue was. Missing the aggregate function within the series.

```
subtract([
    sum([
        s("measure1", "*", {function:"sum"}),
        s("measure2", "*", {function:"sum"})
    ]),
    s("measure3", "*", {function:"sum"})
])
```